# How to add react-native-splash-screen with react-native-navigation v2

Tags: android-studio, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am using react-native-navigation v2 in my project, when i follow the step 6 of initial setup of react-native-navigation [v2](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing?id=_6-update-mainactivityjava)

then following changes are done by me in **MainActivity.java**

```
-import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
+import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;

-public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity { 
+public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
-    @Override
-    protected String getMainComponentName() {
-        return "yourproject";
-    }
}
```

when i am follow the initial setup step in [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen#third-stepplugin-configuration)

```
 import android.os.Bundle; // here 
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
// react-native-splash-screen >= 0.3.1 
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // here 
// react-native-splash-screen < 0.3.1 
import com.cboy.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // here 

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    // ...other code 
}
```

then there is a conflict, as **MainActivity** is now **extends** **NavigationActivity** instead of **ReactActivity** , and to follow initial setup of react-native-splash-screen i need to **override**  **ReactActivity** , What should i do now, to add react-native-splash-screen with react-native-navigation v2?

Comment: I don't think you'll face an issue with it. just go ahead :)

Comment: did you find a solid way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it just like this :

```
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.